# How to run a program by being activated in another program in python

Tags: python

I am fairly new to programming and I would like to know if running a different file by command  For example:

```
userInput = input("Hello, which game would you like to go to? Battleship, rock-paper-scissors, or Farkle?")
if userInput == "Battleship":
  #runs Battleship.py
elif userInput == "rock-paper-scissors":
  #runs RockPaperScissors.py
elif userInput == "Farkle":
  #runs Farkle.py
else:
  print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
```

Comment: The answer is "yes", but there are better ways of doing this. What is the real question here? What are you trying to achieve? Edit the question and put in some code you've written and describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: @jdv I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have two `.py` files:

- `script1.py`: You want to call another program or Python script from this file
- `script2.py`: This file you want to execute

You now have multiple options:

1. **Treat the other file like a module (import it):** In `script1.py` write:

   `import script2` (Note: The files have to be in the same directory.)
2. **Spawn a shell process**: In `script1.py` write:

   ```
   import os
   os.system('python /path/to/script2.py')
   ```
3. **Use** `call` **from the** `subprocess` **module**: In `script1.py` write:

   ```
   import subprocess
   subprocess.call(['python', '/path/to/script2.py'])
   ```

Option 1 should be the preferred one when 'calling' another python file. The other ones you can use to run non-Python stuff, for example a Bash command:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['ls'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "Program" you mean function, then

```
def foo():
    # Put your code here

userInput = input("Would you like to go to program 2?  ")
if userInput == "yes":
  foo()
```

---

Or from another file (In my case `bar.py`)

`bar.py`

```
def foo():
    # Code here
```

`main.py` (*your original file*)

```
userInput = input("Would you like to go to program 2?  ")
if userInput == "yes":
  bar.foo()
```

Comment: No, I mean a different file.

Comment: @VirusFreeNewt Added

Comment: Would it be clean coding to define a whole program as a function to do that same thing?

Comment: @VirusFreeNewt What do you mean by that same thing?

Comment: I mean instead of defining one part of some code from one file as a function, defining a whole program as a function.

Comment: @VirusFreeNewt The entire program is a compilation of functions. So you could say that the entire program is a function to call your other functions.